# Is there an existing online photobook creation tool implemented in HTML, CSS and JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ria, saas

I'm researching the possibility of putting together a Rich Internet Application (think Google Docs or [ProtoShare](http://www.protoshare.com/)) for creating photobooks (like [ShutterFly](http://www.shutterfly.com/)).  The finished books will be printed in Asia by our client's preferred print partner.

To enable as wide an audience as possible to access the application (e.g. iPad and SmartPhone) users, we'd like to explore the possibility of building the app in HTML, CSS and JavaScript.

Some features I'd like to include are:

- Crop, rotate and resize of images
- Basic post-processing such as brightness & contrast adjustment
- Support for video files, recording footage from webcam
- Templated page layouts with image placeholders

As the project is very broad in scope, and we're still in the early stages I'm seeking to get a feel for whether or not this will be possible. I'd be very interested to hear of existing examples that have been built without Flash, or just getting a "gut feel" about whether or not this should even be attempted.

Comment: hi paul, if you are still looking for this, I'd love to chat with you. I am working on an HTML photobook that does exactly this as a personal project, and am thinking about how to make the business happen. I am a better coder than networker.

Comment: @AleksandarTotic - We ended up using Flash in the end as the deadline, coupled with very stringent design and behavioural guidelines made considering anything else nigh-on impossible.  You can see the fruits of our labours at http://www.milkbooks.com/ :)

Answer (score 3):

My company has an app that does Marketing Automation and we have a similar tool built to design postcards, letters, and emails that we send to a printer for the client automatically.  I HATE Flash (it's slowly dying, thank goodness!) so I insisted on pure HTML, CSS, and JQuery with a PHP backend.  I've been doing UI development for about 15 years and this is by far the toughest challenge I've ever faced due to the many intricacies involved.

I approached the task using JQuery's Draggable (and other) functionality to establish positioning of elements.  It's tricky to deal with overflows and overlaps, so expect to be fighting with that for a good portion of your programming.  I approached "gutters" by making my editable area offset from the actual background, which meant that I didn't have to program an additional "off limits" area.  To handle "layers" of elements, each page has a selectable/droppable list of each added element such as pictures, text, design elements, etc.  Saving occurs automatically via jQuery Ajax every 5 minutes from the time the user opens the window.  X,Y coordinates save to a MySQL database for later editing or for sending to the printer.

Here's the thing.  We have a VERY specialized printer who bends over backwards for us.  We communicate on a daily basis with them and have established a process to ensure our work gets from clients to approval to the printer to the fulfillment house smoothly.  It wasn't an easy road to get to that point!  If you're going to a run-of-the-mill printer to do your output, expect near daily headaches as clients output designs that the printer will tell you can't be done, after which you'll have to re-adjust your app.  There's SO many different ways the client can create something that will throw the printer a curveball that there's virtually no way to account for all of them.  If it was me and I was going down this road, I might actually consider the purchase of a quality color printer as part of my business plan so I could control the process entirely.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  Does your app produce a PDF or some other print-ready file?  I have edited the question as my client already has arrangements with a printer in Asia.

Comment: An offshore printer... The plot thickens!

Comment: Is your app on the public internet?  If so, would you pass on the URL? I'd be really interested in seeing what you've achieved. 
@Jared - Yep, it's getting pretty sticky already!

Comment: Actually, it doesn't come out as a .pdf yet, but that is something that we might approach for the future.  The printer actually prefers it as a tab separated data file with merge content (name, address, copy, etc) and a separate tab delimited file for layout information (x/y positions, elements) as well as an automated FTP upload of images.  They do some sort of complex merging using Fiery software to get the final result.  The app is on the public internet, but it's not open enough to see, unfortunately.  I may do a blog post on its construction in the future.